# Changing Host-Only Value of the Identity Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-3.0

It is a pretty simple Task, I want to change the `Host-Only` value of my Cookie Authentication Cookie. I know that you can change a lot of the Auth-Cookie Settings in this method `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>{...})`, but I couldn't find a property which would change the `Host-Only` value.

I already tried to find something online, but I couldn't find anything to it.

#### Note:

I am using `ASP.Net Core 3 pre-release 9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option for this because it's not a configurable thing; it just is or is not. Cookies are domain-bound to begin with. By default, the cookie will be set on the *exact* host, i.e. `foo.example.com`, which then makes it "host only" by default. It will only ever be available to `foo.example.com`, no matter what.

You *could* set the cookie domain to a wildcard `.example.com`, in which case it would be available to all subdomains (`example.com`, `www.example.com`, `foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com`, etc.). That would no longer be "host only" in the sense that there's technically multiple hosts the cookie will apply to (though all for the same base domain). However, if you didn't want that, then you would simply not use this type of cookie domain; there's still no need for some sort of additional configuration option, i.e. if you want "host only" then just use the exact host as the cookie domain.